# Posicionamento de label

Tags: css, css3

Utilizo o JQuery Validate para fazer a validação de inputs, porém quando a validação falha, é criado um label de mensagem de erro ao lado do input.

**Meu objetivo é fazer com que esse label seja mostrado abaixo do input, sem alterar a posição dos inputs ao lado do input validado**, mas quando utilizo a propriedade CSS 'display: block', os inputs ao lado são empurrados para baixo, como se houvesse um '< br >' entre os inputs e o label de erro gerado pela validação.

Segue demonstração

Antes da validação:
[image: Antes]
Depois da validação:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código CSS do label de erro é muito simples:

```
label.error {
font: 11px arial;
margin-left: 2px;
display: block; }
```

Caso minha pergunta esteja incompleta, por favor me avise que irei complementar a pergunta o mais rápido possível.

Comment: Como aparecia antes de vc colocar display block? Por cima dos outros inputs ao lado?

Comment: Pode postar o HTML só dessa parte desses 3 campos?

Comment: Vc tentou com `display:inline-block`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode converter esse `label` para `position: absolute` e posicioná-lo abaixo do `input`. No entanto é preciso que o elemento onde a `label` é criada tenha `position: relative`. Inclua no CSS o código abaixo para setar todos os elementos com `position: relative`:

```
*{
   position: relative;
}
```

É importante também que cada `input` esteja separado um do outro dentro de um elemento (uma `div` ou `label`, por exemplo):

```
<form>
    <div>
        E-mail <input ...>
    </div>
    <div>
        Telefone <input ...>
    </div>
    <div>
        Telefone adicional <input ...>
    </div>
</form>
```

E o CSS abaixo irá posicionar a `label`:

```
label.error{
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 23px;
   margin-left: 0;
}

*{
   position: relative;
}
```

**Veja como fica:**

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $.validator.setDefaults({
  submitHandler: function() {
   alert("submitted!");
  }
 });

 $().ready(function() {
  // validate the comment form when it is submitted
  $("#commentForm").validate();

  // validate signup form on keyup and submit
  $("#signupForm").validate({
   rules: {
    firstname: "required",
    lastname: "required",
    username: {
     required: true,
     minlength: 2
    },
    password: {
     required: true,
     minlength: 5
    },
    confirm_password: {
     required: true,
     minlength: 5,
     equalTo: "#password"
    },
    email: {
     required: true,
     email: true
    },
    topic: {
     required: "#newsletter:checked",
     minlength: 2
    },
    agree: "required"
   },
   messages: {
    firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
    lastname: "Please enter your lastname",
    username: {
     required: "Please enter a username",
     minlength: "Your username must consist of at least 2 characters"
    },
    password: {
     required: "Please provide a password",
     minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
    },
    confirm_password: {
     required: "Please provide a password",
     minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long",
     equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
    },
    email: "Please enter a valid email address",
    agree: "Please accept our policy",
    topic: "Please select at least 2 topics"
   }
  });

  // propose username by combining first- and lastname
  $("#username").focus(function() {
   var firstname = $("#firstname").val();
   var lastname = $("#lastname").val();
   if (firstname && lastname && !this.value) {
    this.value = firstname + "." + lastname;
   }
  });

  //code to hide topic selection, disable for demo
  var newsletter = $("#newsletter");
  // newsletter topics are optional, hide at first
  var inital = newsletter.is(":checked");
  var topics = $("#newsletter_topics")[inital ? "removeClass" : "addClass"]("gray");
  var topicInputs = topics.find("input").attr("disabled", !inital);
  // show when newsletter is checked
  newsletter.click(function() {
   topics[this.checked ? "removeClass" : "addClass"]("gray");
   topicInputs.attr("disabled", !this.checked);
  });
 });
 </script>
 <style>
 #commentForm {
  width: 500px;
 }
 #commentForm label {
  width: 250px;
 }
 #commentForm label.error, #commentForm input.submit {
  margin-left: 253px;
 }
 #signupForm {
  width: 670px;
 }
 #signupForm label.error {
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: auto;
  display: inline;
 }
 #newsletter_topics label.error {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 103px;
 }
   
   form div{
      display: inline-block;
   }
   
   .submit{
      margin-top: 20px;
   }

label.error{
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 23px;
   margin-left: 0;
}

*{
   position: relative;
}

 </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">

 <form class="cmxform" id="signupForm" method="get" action="" style="width: 1000px; display: block;">
  <fieldset>
   <div>
    <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
    <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text">
   </div>
   <div>
    <label for="lastname">Lastname</label>
    <input id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text">
   </div>
   <div>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input id="username" name="username" type="text">
   </div>
   <p>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
   </p>
  </fieldset>
 </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado pelo suporte!